# Can a long enough tube block all air flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm asking because of the concept of a fluid flow creating a boundary layer region that increases in size as the fluid progresses down the length of the tube. Like in a wind tunnel. The flow can apparently be restricted by the boundary layer and, just like a normal constriction, speed it up in the center.

Is there a length at which the boundary layer created by the flow in the tube completely obstructs the flow?

Here's a diagram of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Not really. The boundary layer in this case is not a hard boundary, in that fluid still flows within the boundary. The stable state of laminar flow within the pipe is [Poiseuille flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation), which is inversely proportional to the length of the pipe (delta-x in wiki link). The concept of boundary layers seems to be used more as a heuristic here, so it probably shouldn't be taken too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The flow can apparently be restricted by the boundary layer and, just like a normal constriction, speed it up in the center.

Boundary layer is *not* a constriction in the same way that a hard wall is. Boundary layer is that region of the flow where fluid has slowed down (but is still flowing), by virtue of fluid viscosity and no-slip condition at the tunnel walls. If flow slows down inside the boundary layer (wall region of the pipe), then it must speed up outside the boundary layer (central region of the pipe) to maintain the same mass flow rate. However, speeding up of the flow outside the boundary layer doesn't proceed indefinitely, but reaches a maximum value when boundary layers from the walls merge, resulting in a fully developed flow.

> Is there a length at which the boundary layer created by the flow in the tube completely obstructs the flow?

No. The "constriction-like" effect (speeding up of flow at the pipe centre) is created by the flow itself (i.e. slowing of fluid inside the boundary layer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's really interesting. I'll have to look into fully developed flows.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary layer will increase in thickness with distance along the duct until its outer edge reaches the center of the duct.  After that, you will have fully developed flow in the duct, with the maximum velocity at the center, and zero velocity at the wall.  So the flow in the duct will definitely not get plugged.  The mass flow rate will be constant, and the pressure gradient will be given by the Darcy Weisbach correlation (if the duct diameter is constant).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you saying the average mass flow rate is constant once the flow is fully developed or are you saying that in a cross section of the flow (once it is fully developed) the mass flow is the same across the cross section? I assume you meant the first (or something similar) since the boundary layer would still be slowing the air at the walls so I don't see how the walls could have the same mass flow rate as the center.